# Pandas filling in the missing data when the dataset has "-" and "None" cells

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with a dataset that has "-" in the sourceusername column and "None" in the sourcehostname column of this dataframe.  The IP usually stays the same for desktops, but changes for laptops.  I am trying to fill in the blanks using the information I have. This data frame has computers where a user will log off and a new user will log in and create proxy traffic.  This is what the dataframe looks like:

```
 df
    sourceusername  sourcehostname  sourceaddress   destinationhostname
 0  1111            Computer_1      10.11.2.22      khms0.google.com
 1  1111            Computer_1      10.11.2.22      photos.wavebid.com
 2  1112            Computer_2      10.11.2.23      www.msn.com
 3  1113            Computer_3      10.11.2.24      log.pinterest.com
 4  1113            Computer_3      10.11.2.24      apx.moatads.com
 5  -               None            10.11.2.23      pixabay.com
 6  -               Computer_3      10.11.2.24      rb.adnxs.com
 7  1111            None            10.11.2.22      dt.adsafeprotected.com
 8  1111            Computer_1      10.11.2.22      ad.doubleclick.net
 9  -               None            10.11.2.23      s0.2mdn.net
10  1114            Computer_1      10.11.2.22      khms2.google.com
11  -               None            10.11.2.22      photos.wavebid.com
12  1113            Computer_3      10.11.2.24      log.pinterest.com
```

Desired output:

```
 df
    sourceusername  sourcehostname  sourceaddress   destinationhostname
 0  1111            Computer_1      10.11.2.22      khms0.google.com
 1  1111            Computer_1      10.11.2.22      photos.wavebid.com
 2  1112            Computer_2      10.11.2.23      www.msn.com
 3  1113            Computer_3      10.11.2.24      log.pinterest.com
 4  1113            Computer_3      10.11.2.24      apx.moatads.com
 5  1112            Computer_2      10.11.2.23      pixabay.com
 6  1113            Computer_3      10.11.2.24      rb.adnxs.com
 7  1111            Computer_1      10.11.2.22      dt.adsafeprotected.com
 8  1111            Computer_1      10.11.2.22      ad.doubleclick.net
 9  1112            Computer_2      10.11.2.23      s0.2mdn.net
10  1114            Computer_1      10.11.2.22      khms2.google.com
11  1114            Computer_1      10.11.2.22      photos.wavebid.com
12  1113            Computer_3      10.11.2.24      log.pinterest.com
```

As you can see the user "1114" at index 10 is a new user on "Computer_1".  What is the best way to tackle filling in the missing data?

Comment: For those rows with missing data, you want to fill them with data that has the same IP?

Comment: Yes but when a new user logs into a computer they may still have the same IP but different username and or Computer name.  Think of this as a time series where index 0 is the first event of the day.

Comment: For row 3, how to come up with the conclusion to fill up sourceusername with 1113? It could possibly be 1115 using Computer_3, which indicate that a user 1115 used Computer_3 right?

Comment: That's true I guess it could be, I'm scratching my head on how to do this.

Comment: I am not able to notice the pattern in the imputation. Can you please elaborate on how the missing values should be imputed?

Comment: So the IP would be a "key" of sort.  A user and a computer would be tied to an IP until another user logs into it the same computer, then usually they would have the same IP and computer but the user would change.  There is also the chance that a computer(like a laptop) when a user logs in it can pick up an available IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following gives the desired output which has been posted:

Append `sourceaddress` to the Index because the row number is like a time-series as discussed in the comments

```
df = df.set_index('sourceaddress', append=True)
```

Swap the `Index` levels and then sort the `MultiLevel` Index to effectively show the "chronological" order of events grouped-by each IP address

```
df = df.swaplevel().sort_index()
```

Now `df` looks like the following with a 2-level MultiIndex:

```
                 sourceusername sourcehostname     destinationhostname
sourceaddress                                                         
10.11.2.22    0            1111     Computer_1        khms0.google.com
              1            1111     Computer_1      photos.wavebid.com
              7            1111           None  dt.adsafeprotected.com
              8            1111     Computer_1      ad.doubleclick.net
              10           1114     Computer_1        khms2.google.com
              11              -           None      photos.wavebid.com
10.11.2.23    2            1112     Computer_2             www.msn.com
              5               -           None             pixabay.com
              9               -           None             s0.2mdn.net
10.11.2.24    3            1113     Computer_3       log.pinterest.com
              4            1113     Computer_3         apx.moatads.com
              6               -     Computer_3            rb.adnxs.com
              12           1113     Computer_3       log.pinterest.com
```

Replace '-' and 'None' with `np.nan` and use forward-filling of nan values to effectively fill your pseudo-time series which we have grouped by IP address

```
df = df.replace('-', np.nan).replace('None', np.nan).ffill()
```

Move the `sourceaddress` from the `Index` into the data to get the format we started with:

```
df = df.reset_index(level='sourceaddress').sort_index()
```

Reorder the columns

```
df = df.reindex(columns=['sourceusername', 'sourcehostname', 'sourceaddress', 'destinationhostname'])
```

The result is as follows:

```
   sourceusername sourcehostname sourceaddress     destinationhostname
0            1111     Computer_1    10.11.2.22        khms0.google.com
1            1111     Computer_1    10.11.2.22      photos.wavebid.com
2            1112     Computer_2    10.11.2.23             www.msn.com
3            1113     Computer_3    10.11.2.24       log.pinterest.com
4            1113     Computer_3    10.11.2.24         apx.moatads.com
5            1112     Computer_2    10.11.2.23             pixabay.com
6            1113     Computer_3    10.11.2.24            rb.adnxs.com
7            1111     Computer_1    10.11.2.22  dt.adsafeprotected.com
8            1111     Computer_1    10.11.2.22      ad.doubleclick.net
9            1112     Computer_2    10.11.2.23             s0.2mdn.net
10           1114     Computer_1    10.11.2.22        khms2.google.com
11           1114     Computer_1    10.11.2.22      photos.wavebid.com
12           1113     Computer_3    10.11.2.24       log.pinterest.com
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, I really appreciate it! @jeschwar